# Executing for loop inside if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop, logic

I can't figure it out why my program won't start executing the `for` loop: the logic for the `for` loop is correct, but when the program runs it just skips the `for` loop, without executing it. If `i` is equal to `count`, it should read last remaining elements from array called `se` and write to array `finallyDone`.

```
while(check && i < len){
    int fi = first[i];
    int se = second[j];
    if(fi < se){
        finallyDone[count] = fi;
        i++;
    }
    else{
        finallyDone[count] = se;
        j++;
    }
    int l;
    if(i >= len){
        for(l = count; l < len * 2 - count; l++){
            finallyDone[count + 1] = se;
        }
        check = false;
    }
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Just debug it. check is probably false and/or i is smaller than len

Comment: To figure the for loop, we need to know the value of count and len upon the loop. And from this portion of code, I won't know the value of both of them. Therefore just trace through the loop with a debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where it goes wrong:

```
while(check && i < len){
   //and later
    if(i >= len){
```

You can only walk to the IF-statement if `i` is smaller than `len`, but you will only walk into the IF-statement if `i` is equal to `len` or bigger. Those two statements are contradictory.

Comment: Not entirely true, if i == len-1 and fi < se then i will be equal to len. You need the input data to be able to correctly analyze/debug this.

Comment: Nope, the i++ happens at the location of your //and later comment, and I see no continue or break statement.